# Is this an example of apposition?

Tags: grammar

There is a sentence like:

> The most miserable people, the unemployed, are not the idle people.'

Are the noun phrases 'The most miserable people' and 'the unemployed' in apposition here?

Comment: Yes, "the unemployed" is an appositive here, a supplementary (non-restrictive) appositive to be precise since it is separated from "the most miserable people" with a comma.

Answer (score 2):

*The most miserable people, the unemployed, are not the idle people*.

Yes, the NP "The unemployed” is an appositive. But it is not of the modifying kind since it is separated from "the most miserable people" with commas. It is still an appositive, but more specifically a supplementary appositive, the non-restrictive kind. It is a crucial difference.

By definition, appositive dependents are ones which when substituted for the matrix noun phrase systematically yield a clause which is an entailment of the original. For example, in "She sang in the opera Carmen", dropping "opera" would yield "She sang in Carmen", a genuine entailment of the original. Note also that a proper name can occur as ‘head’ with a definite NP as appositive: "She sang in Carmen the opera", where now "the opera" becomes the appositive modifier.

With integrated appositives, like that example, "Carmen" is a modifier of "opera", identifying which opera is being referred to. But in, say, "Bizet’s most popular opera, Carmen, was first produced in 1875", things are different: "Carmen" is now not a modifier but a supplement to "Bizet’s most popular opera" (called the 'anchor'), and since there can only be one entity satisfying that description the supplement is non-restrictive.

So, back to your example: "the unemployed" (notice how it’s set off with commas in your example) is a supplement (not a modifier) to the anchor "the most miserable people" and as such is inherently non-restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

The proper term is "[apposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition)".

The two phrases are "in apposition", that is, one serves to identify the other.

"The unemployed" is the appositive.

Compare:

> **The gypsies, Snap and Pedro**,
>   Are none of Tom's comradoes,
>   The punk I scorn and the cutpurse sworn,
>   And the roaring boy's bravadoes.
>   **The meek, the white, the gentle**
>   Me handle, touch, and spare not;
>   But those that cross Tom Rynosseros
>   Do what the panther dare not.

In line 1, the two bolded phrases are in apposition.

In line 5, the bolded phrases are merely elements of a list.

Comment: Aren't they appositive of each other?

Comment: @JimReynolds - hm.. I don't know. Are they?

Comment: Oh. No. You're right.

Comment: @JimReynolds It's the second noun that is the appositive modifier. The first noun is 'head' of the NP; it is the noun that is being modified by the appositive modifier.

Comment: @Bill Thanks. I had thought that all such related elements were apposite of each other. Appositive of?